# How to add a column to csv stored in a variable

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to add 2 new columns to a csv file in python

the code would select data from the same csv file and should make a new column and add the data in those columns.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv")

print(data.iloc[1])

data = pd.read_csv("newdata.csv")

row2 = data.iloc[1:5]

print(row2)
```

this is how far I've gone till now

newdata.csv :-

```
date,temp
20160101-00:00,08
20160101-03:00,10
20160101-06:00,20
20160101-09:00,23
20160101-12:00,21
20160101-18:00,11
20160101-21:00,10
```

the output I want :-

```
20160101-00:00,08,20160102-00:00,09
20160101-03:00,10,20160102-03:00,09
20160101-06:00,20,20160102-06:00,20
20160101-09:00,23,20160102-12:00,20
20160101-12:00,21,20160102-12:00,20
20160101-18:00,11,20160102-18:00,10
20160101-21:00,10,20160102-21:00,09
```

I am new to this lannguage so can anyone please suggest something
thanks :)

Comment: The first _new_ column seems to result from adding 1 day the first _old_ column. But what is the logic behind the second _new_ column?

Answer (score 0):

To define new column in Dataframe you can use below;

```
df['new_column_name'] = new_list
```

In your case it would be :

```
df['new_column_name'] = data.iloc[1]
```